# Android Jetpack Compose Media3 HLS Stream with playback service

Tags: android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, android-mediasession, android-media3, exoplayer-media-item

I would like to get HLS streaming working using Media3 with a background playback service. I see references online on how to use MediaController `setMediaItem` in the activity/composable, however, not sure how to use media source which also uses custom HTTP header. Here is my composable function.

```
@Composable
fun PlayerTest(
    token: String,
    url: String,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val dataSourceFactory = DataSource.Factory {
        val dataSource = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().createDataSource()
        dataSource.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token)
        dataSource
    }

    val hlsMediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(url))

    val sessionToken = SessionToken(context, ComponentName(context, PlaybackService::class.java))
    val controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(context, sessionToken).buildAsync()

    DisposableEffect(
        Box {
            AndroidView(
                factory = {
                    PlayerView(context).apply {
                        resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL
                        useController = false
                        layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
                    }
                },
                update = { playerView ->
                    controllerFuture.addListener({
                        val controller = controllerFuture.get()
                        controller.setMediaSource(hlsMediaSource) // <--- NOT FOUND
                        playerView.setPlayer(controller)
                    }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())
                }
            )

            AudioPlayer(...)
        },
    ) {
        onDispose {
            MediaController.releaseFuture(controllerFuture)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I don't see options in MediaItem.Builder() that takes media source. I am using Media3 version `1.3.0`. Any suggestions?

The method `setMediaSource` is available in ExoPlayer implementation which is created in the service. Or should I let service build the URL and pass setMediaSource instead of doing it in the composable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to think how media are operated on UI layer because `MediaSessionService` can cope with it.
UI layer just connects `MediaSessionService` through `SessionToken` which builds `MediaController`, and you can set it to `PlayerView`.

#### SampleVideoScreen.kt

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SampleVideoScreen(viewModel: SampleVideoViewModel) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    DisposableEffect(viewModel) {
        viewModel.prepare(context)
        onDispose { viewModel.dispose() }
    }

    val controller by viewModel.mediaController.observeAsState()
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            PlayerView(context)
        },
        update = { playerView ->
            playerView.player = controller
        }
    )

}
```

#### SampleVideoViewModel.kt

```kotlin
class SampleVideoViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private var sessionToken: SessionToken? = null
    val mediaController = MutableLiveData<MediaController>()

    fun prepare(context: Context) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val playIntent = Intent(context, PlaybackService::class.java)
                .setAction("playSample")
                .putExtra("url", "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")
            context.startService(playIntent)
            val component = ComponentName(context, PlaybackService::class.java)
            sessionToken = SessionToken(context, component).also { session ->
                MediaController.Builder(context, session)
                    .buildAsync().get().also { controller ->
                        mediaController.postValue(controller)
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    fun dispose() {
        mediaController.value?.clearMediaItems()
        mediaController.postValue(null)
    }
}
```